# Modelling a forum with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to model a forum with Neo4j. I have "forums" nodes which have messages and, optionally, these messages have replies: forum-->message-->reply

The cypher query I am using to retrieve the messages of a forum and their replies is:

```
start forum=node({forumId}) match forum-[*1..]->msg 
where (msg.parent=0 and msg.ts<={ts} or msg.parent<>0) 
return msg ORDER BY msg.ts DESC limit 10
```

This query retrieves the messages with time<=ts and all their replies (a message has parent=0 and a reply has parent<>0)

My problem is that I need to retrieve pages of 10 messages (limit 10) independently of the number or replies.

For example, if I had 20 messages and the first one with 100 replies, it would only return 10 rows: the first message and 9 replies but I need the first 10 messages and the 100 replies of the first one.

How can I limit the result based on the number of messages and not their replies?

The ts property is indexed, but is this query efficient when mixing it with other where clauses?

Do you know a better way to model this kind of forum with Neo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you switch to labels and avoid IDs (as they can be recycled and therefore are not stable identifiers):

```
MATCH (forum:FORUM)<--(message:MESSAGE {parent:0})
WHERE forum.name = '%s' // where %s identifies the forum in a *stable* way
WITH message // using a subquery allows to apply LIMIT only to main messages
ORDER BY message.ts DESC
LIMIT 10

OPTIONAL MATCH (message)<-[:REPLIES_TO]-(replies)
RETURN message, replies
```

The only important change here is to split the reply and message matching in two sub-queries, so that the LIMIT clause applies to the first subquery only.

However, you need to link the relevant replies to the matched main messages in the second subquery (I introduced a fictional relationship REPLIES_TO to link replies to messages).

And when you need to fetch page 2,3,4 etc.
You need an extra parameter (which the biggest message timestamp of the previous page, let's say previous_timestamp).

The first sub-query WHERE clause becomes:

```
WHERE forum.name = '%s' AND message.ts > previous_timestamp
```

Comment: With "where has(forum.name) and forum.name=" and "OPTIONAL MATCH" in the second subquery it works great. With "MATCH" only it only returns the messages with replies. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch for OPTIONAL MATCH, I'll update my answer! Regarding `has`, it means that some nodes labeled with FORUM do not have a name attribute?

Comment: No, at least in version 2.0.0, with forums and messages using different labels, "where forum.name=" is also evaluated with nodes of type message that don't have the "name" property. I'll investigate it.

Comment: Did you specify the `FORUM` label in `MATCH` clause for the `forum` variable?

Comment: It works: `MATCH (forum:FORUM) where forum.name='f1' RETURN forum`
It doesn't: `MATCH (forum:FORUM)<--(message:MESSAGE) where forum.name='f1' RETURN forum` ---->
`The property 'name' does not exist on Node[2]` <-- `Node[2]` is a message node

Comment: Wow, that is really weird. I'll forward that to the Neo4j team, I don't understand it.